# get not working with dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Create a dictionary containing the frequency of each character in a given string

```
    str1 = "peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers"
    freq = {}
    freq2 = {}
    for c in str1:
        freq[c] = freq.get(c, 0) + 1
    freq2 = {c: freq2.get(c, 0) + 1 for c in str1}
    print(freq)
    print(freq2)
```

***Output***

```
{'p': 9, 'e': 8, 't': 1, 'r': 3, ' ': 7, 'i': 3, 'c': 3, 'k': 3, 'd': 2, 'a': 1, 'o': 1, 'f': 1, >'l': 1, 's': 1}

{'p': 1, 'e': 1, 't': 1, 'r': 1, ' ': 1, 'i': 1, 'c': 1, 'k': 1, 'd': 1, 'a': 1, 'o': 1, 'f': 1, >'l': 1, 's': 1}
```

I just wanted to know why dictionary comprehension is not giving me the right answer?

Comment: `freq2.get(c, 0)` is always `0`, the new `freq2` dict is only bound *after* the dict comphrneions is completed

Comment: Just a silly but perhaps interesting other way that does work: `freq2.update((c, freq2.get(c, 0) + 1) for c in str1)`

Comment: btw: if you have a line like `freq2 = { ...`, then you don't need the previous `freq2 = {}`.

Comment: Did you mean: `freq2 = copy(freq)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looping using the dictionary comprehension, `freq2` is yet to be updated and all values are non-existent so `get` returns `0` (and you add `1` so assigned value to keys is `1` to a ***new dictionary***).

Only after the dictionary comprehension, `freq2` is updated (with the dictionary created by the dictionary comprehension).

The steps are:

1. At line 5; `freq2` is empty
2. At line 6; first, a new dictionary created by looping on `freq2` empty dictionary. Then, that new dictionary is assigned to `freq2`

Comment: Welcome @AayushGupta :)